# asp.net (IIS 7.5) images/css give 500 error but work fine after login

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a smart-card enabled website where in IIS, Anonymous Authentication is disabled, SSL is enabled.

The IIS root also has Anonymous Authentication disabled, but Active Directory Client Certificate Authentication enabled.
Static Content role service is also installed.

In the web.config, I have

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Following that, I have

```
    <location path="/css/main.css"> 
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
    <location path="images"> 
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

In both the `css` and `images` folders, I also have web.config's consisting of:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I use an AppPool running with a custom identity, let's say APUser

On the web server for those folders, I have permissions set to read for APUser, IUSR, Anonymous Logon, Users, IIS_IUSRS, and Everyone.

The url is in trusted sites on the browser.

Initially, the images and css return error 500 (using network capture with dev tools).  After logging in, they show fine.
Same issue running on the server itself.

If I enable Anonymous Authentication in IIS, disable Active Directory Client Certificate, and change `deny users="?"` to `allow users="*"`, everything works fine.

What am I missing to disable Anonymous Authentication, but still show images/css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Group Policy for "Impersonate a client after authentication", add IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 0):

web.config authorization settings works sequentially. That is since you are denying unauthenticated users by using following, it does not read anymore of your config.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.71).aspx).

> Remarks At run time, the authorization module iterates through the
>    and  tags until it finds the first access rule that fits
>   a particular user. It then grants or denies access to a URL resource
>   depending on whether the first access rule found is an  or a
>    rule. The default authorization rule in the Machine.config file
>   is  so, by default, access is allowed unless
>   configured otherwise.

Change it so that they come before your deny unauthenticated user part.

```
  <location path="/css/main.css"> 
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
    <location path="images"> 
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

From "Allow" [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

"users

Required String attribute.

A comma-separated list of user names that are denied access to the resource. A question mark (?) denies anonymous users and an asterisk (*) indicates that all users are denied access."

Now, I take it that there's an error in there and they want to say "allow".

So you want `<allow users="?,*" />`